# why RGB and depth Image synchronization not working? [Solved]

Tags: ros, opencv, synchronization, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

why this works ? but not the bottom one?

```
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>

#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>


#include <sstream>
#include <string>


//names that will appear at the top of each window
static const std::string windowName = "Original Image";

using namespace std;
using namespace sensor_msgs;
using namespace message_filters;


void callback(const ImageConstPtr& image_rgb, const CameraInfoConstPtr& cam_info)
{
    // Solve all of perception here...
    
    cv::Mat image_color = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(image_rgb)->image;
    
    cv::imshow(windowName,image_color);
    
    cv::waitKey(3);
    
}

    


int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "vision_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    message_filters::Subscriber<Image> rgb_sub(nh,"/camera/rgb/image_color", 1);
    message_filters::Subscriber<CameraInfo> info_color_sub(nh,"/camera/rgb/camera_info", 1);

    TimeSynchronizer<Image, CameraInfo> sync(rgb_sub, info_color_sub, 10);
    sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));
    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

In the upper code I'm able to see the RGB image .
BUT

This is not giving any result.
I'm trying to synchronize both the images and then separate then inside callback . then process the RGB image to find the object. I want ti find depth of particular pixel u,v . but this is not working when I'm trying to send both RGB and depth image.

```
void callback(const ImageConstPtr& image_rgb, const ImageConstPtr& image_depth_source)
{
    // Solve all of perception here...
    
    cv::Mat image_color = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(image_rgb)->image;
    cv::Mat image_depth = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(image_depth_source)->image;
    
    cv::imshow(windowName1,image_color);
    cv::imshow(windowName2,image_depth);
    
    cv::waitKey(3);
    
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "vision_node");

    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    
    message_filters::Subscriber<Image> rgb_sub(nh,"/camera/rgb/image_color", 1);
    message_filters::Subscriber<Image> depth_sub(nh,"/camera/depth_registered/image_raw", 1);

    TimeSynchronizer<Image, Image> sync(rgb_sub, depth_sub, 10);
    sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));
    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227059/why-rgb-and-depth-image-synchronization-not-working?-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2016-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2016-02-19**:
Hello I tried to check for the topic /camera/depth_registered/image_raw in rostopic list. but with rostopic hz it's giving no response. then I changed to /camera/depth/image and I got
average rate: 29.960
min: 0.031s max: 0.037s std dev: 0.00194s window: 27.
then also I'm unable to get result.

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2016-02-19**:
with RGB image I got this
subscribed to [/camera/rgb/image_color]
average rate: 30.049
min: 0.030s max: 0.036s std dev: 0.00210s window: 18
average rate: 30.022.

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2016-02-19**:
message_filters::Subscriber rgb_sub(nh,"/camera/rgb/image_color", 1);
message_filters::Subscriber depth_sub(nh,"/camera/depth/image", 1);
TimeSynchronizer<Image, Image> sync(rgb_sub, depth_sub, 10);
sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));
now I'm doing this .

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2016-02-19**:
void callback(const ImageConstPtr& image_rgb, const ImageConstPtr& image_depth_source)
{
cv::Mat image_color = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(image_rgb)->image;
cv::Mat image_depth = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(image_depth_source)->image;

```
cv::imshow(windowName1,image_color);
cv::imshow(windowName2,image_depth);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure that your drivers for your device are setup to publish on both of those topics? What does `rostopic hz` report for each topic? Are you entering your callback? Depending on how synchronized your messages are, you may also need an approximate synchronizer.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2016-02-19**:
hello Thanks a lot . I solved this problem. I used Approximate-time Policy http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-26**:
I've marked @jarvisschultz answer as *the* answer, as he provided you with the solution.